# Jquery Read-more slider for Wordpress front page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

Hi I've been using the "Sliding Read More" plugin for wordpress to expand post-read-more text in the frontpage. The plugin works great as is. But I need it to also expand horizontally when the read-more link is clicked. At the moment it is only expanding horizontally on a second click on the div space. The site is: www.platformbk.nl - THANKS!

Here is the code:

```
var $jslide = jQuery.noConflict();

$jslide(document).ready(function() {

// MY CODE BELOW
var modWidth = 679;
var origWidth = 326;

$('div.box-content').click(function () {
$(this).width(modWidth);
});

// initialise the visibility check
var is_visible = false;

// append show/hide links to the element directly preceding the element with a class of        "toggle"
$jslide('.toggle').prev().append(' <a href="#" class="toggleLink">'+showText+'</a>');

// hide all of the elements with a class of 'toggle'
$jslide('.toggle').hide();

// capture clicks on the toggle links
$jslide('a.toggleLink').click(function() {

// switch visibility
is_visible = !is_visible;


// change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
$jslide(this).html( (!is_visible) ? showText : hideText);

// toggle the display - uncomment the next line for a basic "accordion" style
//$('.toggle').hide();$('a.toggleLink').html(showText);
$jslide(this).parent().next('.toggle').toggle('slow');

// return false so any link destination is not followed
return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace this line :

```
$jslide(this).parent().next('.toggle').toggle('slow');
```

with :

```
$jslide(this).parent().parent().animate({width: '679'}, {duration: "slow" });
$jslide(this).parent().next('.toggle').animate({width: '679'}, {duration: "slow" });
```

Then maybe encapsulate that in a conditional block to resize back to it's former width when toggling.
But you will probably run into other issues like your div boxes being overlapped with others etc.

Hope this helps.